# Issue with putting cond statement in a for loop in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket

So I am very new to Racket (and functional programming) but I am having an issue with putting a cond statement in a for loop. I would like to add more conditions to identify characters in a string. Here is what I'm working with right now.

```
(define (check i)
(cond [(member i  '("(" ")" "+" "-" "*" "/") 
)
        i]
        [(eqv? i "1") "yes"]))
```

With the above function (check "1") will return "yes" and "(check "+")" will return "+". However if I add a for loop, like below, "(check "1")" and "(check "+") will return void.

```
(define (check n)
(for ([i (in-string n)])
(cond [(member i  '("(" ")" "+" "-" "*" "/") 
)
                   i]
        [(eqv? i "1") "yes"])))
```

Can anyone clarify why the for loop has this effect? I have tried alternative methods and I've tried to understand why this happens but I just can't get anywhere.
Thanks

Comment: One issue: `in-string` gives you a sequence of *characters*. They'll never be equal or eqv to *strings*. Since you don't have an `else`, you should be getting an error about `cond` failing to match...

Comment: Plus a plain `for` expression always returns void.

Comment: (using `eqv?` to compare strings isn't a good idea, see https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Equality.html )

Comment: @Shawn Is there a version of the for loop that will return a value?

Comment: Many, depending on what you want to return. https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html

Comment: Nitpick: there are no statements, there are only expressions.